# How can i run this in a batch script? (For)

Tags: batch-file

How can I execute the command below in a batch script?

```
for /L %i in (1,0,2) do (for /f "delims=^" %j in (commands.txt) do cmd.exe /c %j >> output.txt & del commands.txt) & ping -n 2 127.0.0.1
```

It returns: j not expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a batch file you have to double the `%` sign for `for` variables:

```
for /l %%i ...
```

and likewise for `%j` too.

This is also detailed in the documentation `help for`:

> To use the `FOR` command in a batch program, specify `%%variable` instead
>   of `%variable`.

almost right at the start.